# Jenkins does not set all properties for Siebel gateway server

Tags: shell, jenkins, ssh, gateway, siebel

We are currently using Siebel 15.14.

I am trying to start our gateway server by creating a job in Jenkins that executes a script. In turn, the script runs a "set up environment properties" script and the command that start the gateway server.

All these happen over an SSH build step in Jenkins.

Specifically:

1) Jenkins job has 1 build step "execute shell script on remote server using ssh":     /mypath/start_gateway.sh

2) start.gateway.sh contains:
    i) . /mygatewaypath/setupparameters.sh
   ii) /mygatewaypath/gtwysrvr/bin/start_ns -r /mygatewaypath/gtwysrvr

3) setupparameters.sh  contains:

```
 if [ ! -d "$HOME" ]; then
 echo "ERROR: HOME must be set prior to starting the Siebel server!"
 exit 1
fi

SIEBEL_ROOT=/mygatewatpath/gtwysrvr ; export SIEBEL_ROOT
SIEBEL_HOME=/mygatewatpath/gtwysrvr ; export SIEBEL_HOME
.
.  (other variables go here)
.
```

Although the jenkins job has a successful build and prints out:

> executing script:
>
> /var/SP/administration/scripts/start_gateway.sh
>
> started at Mon Sep 18 18:53:48 2017, pid: 147189
>
> > [SSH] exit-status: 0
> >
> > > Finished: SUCCESS

When i try to start the gateway server manager i receive the below error:

Fatal error (2555922): Could not open connection to Siebel Gateway configuration store (%1:%2)., exiting...

Also, if i start the application server (which is based on the above gateway server) , the application server is not started correctly.

It Seems that the environments variables of the setupproperties.sh script are not set fully, so the gateway server start in an unstable state.

Answer (score 0):

try to look at the gateway log file in:

/pathtoyourgateway/log/NameSrvr.log

You should get the error.